# Issue when running Tableau API

Tags: python, tableau-api

When attempt to run below code:
`with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth)`
[image]
The compiler return below error code:
`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tableau.test.wilhelmsen.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/2.4/auth/signin (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))

For the past 2 months it was working, but it is not working now.
`

I am trying to run Tableau API and access some API profile such as Datasource or workbook.
It is suppose return the workbook ID or worksheet ID when run.

However it return error when sign in.

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=tableau.test.wilhelmsen.com - you need to go fix your SSL setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable certificate verification

**server = TSC.Server(server_name, http_options={"verify": False})**